# MySQL show columns with no values on any rows

Tags: mysql

I have a huge table with about 250 columns, some of which don not have value on any of the rows, so I'd like to delete them.

What I'd like to do is find those columns without having to go through manually.

Something like

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `my_table` WHERE count(COLUMN)>0
```

but that obviously doesn't work.

What would the correct SQL be for this ?

thanks

Comment: Having 250 columns means your table design is plain wrong. Do you need some advice on that?

Comment: the table is temporary and was created from a csv import. It will be used to insert data into a more normal DB structure but I need to get rid of the empty columns to see what i'm working with

Comment: maybe this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28726/select-column-names-whose-entries-are-not-null can help?

Comment: thanks Vadim Kokin - that looks exactly what I need !

Answer (score 0):

DELETE from table where field1 IS NULL and field2 IS NULL and ...;